# How to transform a list of numbers into an int with better complexity than O(n)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm generating very big large lists of numbers and I'm interested in transforming that into an integer variable for further computations.

What I have for now is this algorithm based on *adding a trailing 0 and then add the digit* (or it should be):

```py
def integer_representation(digits: list, base: int = 10) -> int:
    result = 0
    multiplier = 1
    for digit in digits:
        if digit > 0:
            result = result*(base**multiplier) + digit
            multiplier = 1
        else:
            multiplier += 1
    return result
```

For example, `integer_representation([1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 5, 0, 2])` returns `10302502` (with type `<int>`).

Problem with this approach is that it has an `O(n)` complexity, which is not optimal for huge arrays (350k digits, for example).

Which would be a fast/efficient alternative for this algorithm?

Comment: Could you clarify why you believe it is possible to do this faster than O(_n_)?

Comment: Since you have to access each digit to guarantee that you obtain the correct value, it is not theoretically possible to do this in less than **O(N)**.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The question sounded better in my mind.

Comment: Sidenote: if you do `for digit in digits`, your code gets a lot simpler and more Pythonic

Comment: @wjandrea that's completely true but I wasn't sure if doing it that way is memory efficient, so I just left it that way. This way is good for parallelization though.

Comment: zeroes at the right get chopped in your code: [12, 0, 0] becomes 12 and not 1200 - is this right?

Comment: @Paddy3118 thanks for mentioning, It should not.

Comment: To be clear, the code in the question is not O(n) time, because arithmetic operations on arbitrarily large integers don't take O(1) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get this done in sub linear time complexity, since all values in the input list need to be consulted.

However, it is true that your code will perform many manipulations with relatively large integers (occupying many bytes each). You can get a major performance boost by using a divide-and-conquer approach so that most calculations concern small integers, and these are combined into somewhat bigger integers (but fewer of them), ...etc, to finally make only one operation with the biggest integers that come out of that "tree".

Compare how this code performs in comparison with yours:

```
def integer_representation(digits: list, base: int = 10) -> int:
    def recur(start, end):
        if start + 1 == end:
            return digits[start]
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        left = recur(start, mid)
        right = recur(mid, end)
        return left * base ** (end - mid) + right

    if digits:
        return recur(0, len(digits))
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, there's a little boost (4s, 87s-83s) when comparing both approaches with 1m elements. Why did you choose recursion?

Comment: For the reasons I explained in my answer: divide and conquer. The leaves of the recursion tree will work with small integers, and there are n/2 leaves. So that means half of all calculations happen with small integers. That is a gain.

Comment: BTW, I get a tremendous gain in my benchmarks on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma679518775459839). Can you share the code you have made the comparison with?

Comment: My mistake, I was comparing the same function because of a typo. After checking again, the difference is 88s vs 1s so... wow. Pity I can't give you more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is still O(n) but i measured it and it was about 20% faster than what you wrote.

```
def f(arr, base=10):
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1):
        if arr[-1-i]:
            res += base**i*arr[-1-i]
    return res
```

edit: not computing `base**i` when digit is zero makes it faster

Comment: That looks really nice. Have you tested it on big arrays (1m elements, for example)?

Comment: Nice! If it helps, you can simplify it: `return sum(base**i*arr[-1-i] for i in reversed(range(len(arr))))`

Comment: I have tested on small arrays but many times. I guess it won't work most of time on 1m elements because of overflow.

Comment: just tested it with a big array with many zeros and it was much slower than yours @loko

Comment: edited again my answer, sorry for the many edits

Comment: No worries, I'm not sure how `range` works but we could assume it's allocating another array in memory with the same length as `arr`. Python 2's `xrange` was a neat way for that... don't know why they deleted it in Python 3.

Comment: No, Python 3's `range` does not allocate an array in memory. It produces an iterator, and only creates a constant size of memory independent of the range. Python 3's `range` is similar to what `xrange` was in Python 2.

Comment: @trincot it's a relief to know that. Been using regular loops fearing it would suppose an innecesary memory allocation. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Udi ignoring the zeroes will return a different result from what was intended.

Comment: @loko why? If arr[-1-i] is zero then base ** i * arr[-1-i] would be zero. So there is no need to add it to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing it numerically, you can work with the string representation of a list of positive integers by removing [ and ], and all the ', ' between the numbers then turning the result into an int. This does much more of the grunt work in fast C code and gives much better timings for 333k single digit ints:

```py
In [36]: def int_rep(digits: list) -> int:
    ...:     "Uses C-coded ops on string representation of list of integers"
    ...:     return int(repr(digits)[1:-1].replace(', ', ''))

In [37]: # 333K single digits

In [38]: digits = n_ints(333_000, range(10))

In [39]: %time x = integer_representation(digits)
Wall time: 26.5 s

In [40]: %time y = int_rep(digits)
Wall time: 1.46 s

In [41]: # example snippet of data

In [42]: len(digits)
Out[42]: 333000

In [43]: digits[234:244]
Out[43]: [3, 0, 4, 1, 0, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: `''.join(map('0123456789'.__getitem__, digits))` is about 30% faster than using `repr` and `replace`, by my benchmark.

Comment: @kaya3 it's almost as fast as generating a list. Please, make it an answer so we can upvote.

Comment: @Paddy3118 shouldn't defining `__repr__` in a class enable avoiding that `replace` and reducing benchmarks?

Comment: @loko: not sure - depends if the standard repr is done using C or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Since you have to access each digit to guarantee that you obtain the correct value, it is not theoretically possible to do this in less than **O(N)**.

*<sub>-- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950711#comment120103396_67950711) by [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune)</sub>*